# SQL select the latest date row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table:

| Invoice | Status | Date | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 44587 | 1 | 02.03.2022 | Awaiting update |
| 44587 | 2 | 07.03.2022 | Processed |

What i really want is to just get the row with the latest date. but since i really want the Explanation column, i keep getting two results...

I try with this:

```
SELECT d.Invoice, d.Status, Max(d.Date), d.Explanation
FROM InvoiceLog d 
WHERE d.Invoice = 44587 
GROUP BY d.Invoice, d.Status, d.Explanation
```

Comment: DATE isn't a date it's a string so you need str_to_date to convert it, and since you only have 2 rows in source then order by desc limit 1 should do.

Comment: I do see some countries which format their dates a `dd.mm.yyyy`, so it could be a date? (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will return the row with the latest 'Date' (Assuming the column's type is indeed Date)

```
SELECT *
FROM InvoiceLog
WHERE Invoice = 44587
ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1
```